# Extension to bring back the full height loading bar in Safari (15+)?

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

Until Safari 4, the loading status filled the address bar completely, which was clearly a clever design feature.

[image]

Even if the actual one mimics this feature, it would be make even more sense to bring it back because of the unified tab bar introduced in Safari 15.

[image]

Is there any extension that would allow this to be achieved in Safari?